# Error in compiling C functions for PostgreSQL 9.6

Tags: c, postgresql

I'm upgrading to PostgreSQL 9.6 and get some errors when trying to compile some C code.

```
gcc -c -o lib/libhaver.o src/libhaver.c -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -Wpointer-arith -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wendif-labels -Wmissing-format-attribute -Wformat-security -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -fPIC -D_GNU_SOURCE -I. -I/usr/pgsql-9.6/include/server -I/usr/pgsql-9.6/include/server/access -I/usr/pgsql-9.6/include/internal -I/usr/include/et -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/usr/include
```

this code:

```
#include "postgres.h"
#include "fmgr.h"

#include "catalog/pg_type.h"
#include "funcapi.h"

#include "utils/guc.h"
#include "access/htup.h"
#include "utils/array.h"

#include "math.h"


#ifdef NEWPOSTGRES
#include "access/htup_details.h"
#endif


PG_MODULE_MAGIC;


// Define a missing value that we can insert into our array
# define FLOAT_NaN (0.0/0.0)

int32 mapAtoB(int32 i, int32 a2, int32 a1); 
PG_FUNCTION_INFO_V1( mapAtoB );
int32 mapAtoB(int32 i, int32 a2, int32 a1){
    int32 j = (i - (a1-a2));
    return j;
}
```

However I get this error:

```
src/libhaver.c:30: error: conflicting types for ‘mapAtoB’
src/libhaver.c:29: note: previous declaration of ‘mapAtoB’ was here
make: *** [lib/libhaver.o] Error 1
```

It works on 9.2 but not on 9.6...  What am I doing wrong??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That looks like you are using the [“version 0 calling convention”](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/xfunc-c.html#AEN53110).

That *should* work in 9.6, but support for it was removed in PostgreSQL v10.

Switch to the version 1 calling convention:

```
PG_FUNCTION_INFO_V1(mapAtoB);

Datum
mapAtoB(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS)
{
    int32   i  = PG_GETARG_INT32(0);
    int32   a2 = PG_GETARG_INT32(1);
    int32   a1 = PG_GETARG_INT32(2);

    PG_RETURN_INT32(i - (a1-a2));
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I had though it was versions 1 since the PG_FUNCTION_INFO_V1 was being called.